# Memcached will not respond to a "get" request till after I issue a "stats" request

Tags: memcached

I'm having a problem with getting memcached to work when accessing it from a server that is outside the internal network AND using a different domain name.  I'm not sure if one, both, or neither of these things are the problem, but it seemed worth noting.

From an internal server (int.edu), I can telnet the memcached server (mem.edu) and everything works great:

a1)

- telnet mem.edu 11211

  - connection occurs
- get foo

  - server responds
- quit

  - quit

Because the above example, I know that my memcached server is working.

From an external server (ext.org), I can telnet the memcached server (mem.edu) but strange things happen:

b1.0)

- telnet mem.edu 11211

  - connection occurs
- get foo

  - server hangs until I get kicked off (within a few min)

b2.0)

- telnet mem.edu 11211

  - connection occurs
- get version

  - server responds
- get foo

  - server hangs until I get kicked off (within a few min)

b3.0)

- telnet mem.edu 11211

  - connection occurs
- stats

  - server responds
- get foo

  - server responds
- get foo2

  - server responds
- quit

  - quit

So as long as I issue a "stats" request before I issue any "get foo" requests, then everything works like normal.  I have no idea why this is?

I have tried using the super verbose memcached logging, but there weren't any differences in the logs between the internal vs external server.

I have talked to my IT department and confirmed that port 11211 is open for DMZ addresses to be able to connect to the memcached server (which makes sense, since I can telnet mem.edu)

I have (unsuccessfully) googled and searched SO, but nothing seems to work.

I have used iptraf (sudo apt-get install iptraf) to monitor what traffic is occurring.  This is another interesting part of the puzzle...  Using the same examples as before for the external server (ext.org):

b1.1)

- telnet mem.edu 11211

  - connection occurs
  - ext.org makes an outgoing request
  - mem.edu receives the request and responds
- get foo

  - server hangs
  - ext.org makes an outgoing request
  - mem.edu NEVER receives the request
  - ext.org keeps making more outgoing requests until the connection ends and I get kicked off

b3.1)

- telnet mem.edu 11211

  - connection occurs
  - ext.org makes an outgoing request
  - mem.edu receives the request and responds
- stats

  - server responds
  - ext.org makes an outgoing request
  - mem.edu receives the request and responds
- get foo

  - server responds
  - ext.org makes an outgoing request
  - mem.edu receives the request and responds
- get foo2

  - server responds
  - ext.org makes an outgoing request
  - mem.edu receives the request and responds
- quit

  - quit
  - ext.org makes an outgoing request
  - mem.edu receives the request and responds

Here is some info about our system:

Memcached version 1.4.4

Memcached was started from an init script, but here is the command used:

```
/usr/bin/memcached -P /var/run/memcached/memcached_11211.pid -d -p 11211 -u memcached -c 1024 -m 64 -vvv
```

Memcached server: mem.edu (CentOS 6.4) -- location:internal (behind firewall rules, etc)

Requesting server1: ext.org (Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS) -- location:DMZ

Requesting server2: int.edu (Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS) -- location:internal

Comment: Given that things seem to work from localhost and not from a remote machine I would bet that there is some sort of networking issue. It's also weird that your getting kicked off of your telnet connection. Memcached won't close a connection like this and that means that something else is probably closing the connection. I would recommend getting a packet trace as a next step to try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, @mikewied, you are correct.  It was definitely a network problem.  However, in talking with my IT department, I didn't get a very clear answer about what the exact problem was.  I will try to get a better idea of the issue and then close/answer the question.